# Executing vba code on sheet modification

Tags: excel, vba

This is my code that lists link to all sheets in main sheet:

```
     For i = 2 To Sheets.Count
          Sheets("main").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("main").Cells(i, 2),_
          Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & Sheets(i).Name & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=Sheets(i).Name
     Next i
```

I would like to execute this code each time a new sheet is added, existing removed, renamed, repositioned.

How can I do that?

P.s.

If there is a better solution i will consider it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would place the code inside the Worksheet_Activate-block of the sheet "Main". This way the hyperlinks are updated every time you activate the sheet.